# $g$ attains both maximum and minimum over $\mathbb{R}$. $f$ is continuous on range of $g$. Does $f\circ g$ necessarily attain maximum on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, optimization, continuity

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function (not necessarily continuous) which attains both its maximum and minimum on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function which is continuous on range of $g$. Does $f\circ g$ necessarily have a maximum on $\mathbb{R}$? Prove or provide a counterexample.

---

**My Solution:**

I don't think that it necessarily attains its maximum on $\mathbb{R}$. I had thought of the following example:

Let
$$g(x) := \begin{cases}
x^2 &\text{if}\; 0<x\leq 10 \\\; 1&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

The range of $g$ is $(0,100]$.

let
$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$. Note that $f$ is continuous on the range of $g$.

$$(f \circ g )(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x}&\text{if}\;0<x\leq 10\\ 1&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

$(f \circ g )(x)$ does not attain its maximum on $\mathbb{R}$.

This is the example that I could come up with, however, $g(x)$ doesn't attain its minimum on $\mathbb{R}$. I am unable to tweak it in a way so as to ensure that it does and the rest of it holds as well.

Another example that I could come up with was the following:

Let
$$g(x) := \begin{cases}
1+x&\text{if}\; 0<x\leq100\\ 
-1&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The range of $g$ is $(1,101] \cup \{-1\}$.

Let $f(x) := \frac1x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$.

$$(f\circ g)(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{1+x}&\text{if}\;0<x\leq 100\\ -1&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

$g$ attains both maximum and minimum and $f\circ g$ does not attain its maximum. But I am unsure if $f$ is continuous on range of $g$ or not. $\frac1x$ is continuous everywhere except at $x=0$. Is that justification enough?

Comment: I've made some relatively numerous edits to hopefully improve formatting, and one to correct the domain of $f$ in your 2nd example ($1/x$ isn't defined at $x=0$). Please check that I haven't messed up the meaning of what you wrote, and remember you can re-edit, or completely roll back the edit if you dislike my edit.

Comment: Yes, your second counterexample is valid and $f$ is continuous on the range of $g$. Your first example does not satisfy the premise that $g$ attains both maximum and minimum but could be fixed via $g(x) = -1 \iff x \notin (0,10]$.

Comment: @Sven-OleBehrend the first example cannot be fixed by such a simple modification, because $f$ is not defined over negative numbers.

Comment: Thank you all! :)